# Android intent to open Instagram with a specified media id

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

Given that I have a media ID of an Instagram image (in the `12345_6789876` format), is there a way to pass it in an Intent to Instagram application so it would open in the target media?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
intent.setComponent(new android.content.ComponentName(
            "com.instagram.android",
            "com.instagram.android.activity.UrlHandlerActivity"));
intent.setData(Uri.parse(mediaId));
```

Comment: This does not work. The UrlHandlerActivity handles instagram.com/p Uris (which are used for permanent links generated for example when clicking "Copy Share URL"), it does not handle media_id data...